# why does islower have to be after .lower() in python

Tags: python

im new to coding in python

why islower() have to be after lower() i.e why is the below statement incorrect

```
phrase = "Hello world!"

print(phrase.islower().lower())
```

like am I not saying False first then change to lower????

Comment: Because 'bool' object `islower()` has no attribute 'lower' as described in the error message

Comment: And if you do the way you say in the title of your question: `print(phrase.lower().islower())`, you don't get `"false"`... Did you tried it?

Comment: thats not wht i was sying @IgnatiusReilly I was stating that doesn't it execute false first then change the false case to lower case. but now I understand

Comment: I haven't downvoted myself, but these are the problems I see: 1) You show an *incorrect statement* but don't explain why it's incorrect (you should post the error message). 2) Lack of research/effort: The error message gives you an explanation of the problem: `'bool' object has no attribute 'lower'`, which, in addition to some basic debugging (like printing the `type(...)` of each intermediate result in the chain, should give you a cue of the problem. Even if you don't get the solution after that, you should include that effort in your question.

Comment: ok ill try that for future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you chain methods, each method is called on the result of the previous method, not the original value. So

```
print(phrase.islower().lower())
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
temp1 = phrase.islower()
temp2 = temp1.lower()
print(temp2)
```

`lower()` is being called on `temp1`, the boolean result of `islower()`, not the string `phrase`. Since booleans don't have a `lower()` method, this gets an error.

Comment: @Aguywithquestions  In addition to this great answer, the same chaining logic applies to many other languages too (not just Python)